# JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: typescript, next.js, tsx

I am relatively new to typescript and trying to diagnose an error. I'm making sidebar navigation and trying to pull an icon from my navigation array.

Array:

```
    const menuItems = [
        { id: 1, label: "Dashboard", icon: <ComputerDesktopIcon />, link: "/" },
        { id: 2, label: "Page 2", icon: <AcademicCapIcon />, link: "" },
        { id: 3, label: "Settings", icon: <Cog6ToothIcon />, link: "/" },
    ];
```

In my code, the error is stemming from this section:

```
<div className="flex flex-col items-start mt-24">
                    {menuItems.map(({ icon: Icon, ...menu }) => {
                        const classes = getNavItemClasses(menu);

                        return <div className={classes}>
                            <Link href={menu.link}>
                                <div className="flex py-2 px-3 items-center w-full h-full">
                                    <div>
                                        <Icon />
                                    </div>
                                    {!toggleCollapse && (
                                        <span className={classNames('text-md font-medium text-dark-gray')}>
                                            {menu.label}
                                        </span>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    })}
                </div>
```

Specifically the `<Icon />` call is throwing the error: `JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures`.

Worth noting everything works perfectly when that line is commented out.

I've worked through building `props` components and other Stack Overflow issues, but where I'm getting caught is in the `menuItems.map` section... most tutorials only define creating + implementing single `const` items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures

`icon` is already a *called* react component that returns *JSX*.

Simply replace `</>` with curly braces `{}`.

```
{menuItems.map(({ icon, ...menu }) => {
   ...
   {icon}
   ...
})}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! Funny how issues that take hours to debug in the early days are usually so simple... so appreciative!

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
{ id: 1, label: "Dashboard", icon: <ComputerDesktopIcon />, link: "/" },
```

You're creating the React element *at that moment*, when you're declaring the object. The `icon` property is now a React element (rather than a functional component in the form of a function, or a class component in the form of a class). Calling a component with `<SomeComponentName />` only makes sense when `SomeComponentName` refers to a component or a class.

The property in the object to pass down should be just the function or class - let it be instantiated with `<Icon />` later.

```
const menuItems = [
    { id: 1, label: "Dashboard", icon: ComputerDesktopIcon, link: "/" },
    { id: 2, label: "Page 2", icon: AcademicCapIcon, link: "" },
    { id: 3, label: "Settings", icon: Cog6ToothIcon, link: "/" },
];
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation. Very helpful—implementing fixes now.